# Auto Layout when ui is loading

Tags: swift, uitableview

when my view is loading some things cause delay and print this error
i have no idea about it
help please

```
2018-05-16 17:07:13.985160+0430 EligashtIOSApp[15125:2090232] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x119492690 UIButton:0x11bcb9d60'\Ue634'.bottom == UIView:0x11b9be6f0.bottom + 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x11b952d50 UIButton:0x11bcb9d60'\Ue634'.bottom == UIView:0x11b9be6f0.bottom   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x119492690 UIButton:0x11bcb9d60''.bottom == UIView:0x11b9be6f0.bottom + 50   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Here you go... https://www.wtfautolayout.com Paste the stuff surrounded by () into it.

Comment: It's not mine but it is very useful :D Really easy to see what's going on with auto layout conflicts :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two constraints in conflict with each other. You have one constraint that says that the button should be 50 px from the bottom of the UIView and one constraint that says it should be 0 px from the bottom of the same view. Both of these can't be true at the same time, so you need to remove one of them.